# How to use user friendly URLs in WordPress with custom query parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding a query string parameter `SpaceID` like this

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = "SpaceID";
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

and the URL is like this:

```
http://MyHost/MyWebSite/space-details/?SpaceID=327
```

and getting the parameter like this

```
 get_query_var('SpaceID');
```

I'm trying to change the URL to be user friendly like this

```
http://MyHost/MyWebSite/space-details/space-name
```

I try like [this article](http://paulstamatiou.com/wordpress-quickie-custom-query-string-plugin/) but is not working.

Comment: Would you add to your question what that article suggested you should do, so there is a permanent record of it? If there is an `.htaccess` file involved, please show us that. Bear in mind that if that link breaks tomorrow (and they often do) we want the question to be useful to readers after that point. Thanks!